# how to use different submit buttons in the same form to work differently for java script and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

Hi I have 1 HTML form with one action attribute and is having total 3 buttons. two of them are made to work according to javascript while the third one is made to work for php. but all of them are calling PHP. Please guide me How to solve this problem

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: use `input type` `submit` for php submission and for javascript try using `button` element

Answer (score 0):

Handle with Ajax submit, so you create three buttons with different ids and on click the each id button you can write three different submit operations.

```
      <form id="target" action="">
        <input type="text" value="Hello there">
        <input type="button" id="submit1" value="Go">
       <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="Go">
    </form>

     $( "#submit1" ).click(function() {
         $( "#target" ).submit();
     });

     $( "#submit2" ).click(function() {
        $( "#target" ).submit();
     });
```

Here target is the form ID

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**For Javascript**

```
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">Button2</button>
```